# NullPointerException with Java array - 8 queens

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I am doing the 8 queens problem and trying to implement the method which will check if there is any collision between queens. When it comes to the logic of the problem, I think I understand it, but I am getting NullpointerException and I can't figure out why. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
private static boolean isOK(int[][] matrix) {
        boolean isInCollision = false;
        Queen [] queens = new Queen[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                if(matrix[i][j] == 1){
                    queens[i] = new Queen(i, j);

                }
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < queens.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < queens.length; j++) {
                if(queens[i].getX()==queens[j].getX() && Math.abs(queens[i].getX()-queens[j].getX())==Math.abs(queens[i].getY()-queens[j].getY())){
                    isInCollision = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return isInCollision;
    }
```

I get error in this line of code:

```
if(queens[i].getX()==queens[j].getX() && Math.abs(queens[i].getX()-queens[j].getX())==Math.abs(queens[i].getY()-queens[j].getY()))
```

Comment: One of the "dot"-operations are returning `null`.  This is why you might want to assign parts of complex expressions to local variables.  This will allow you to identify better where the exception happened.

Answer (score 1):

In the double `for loop` add a test that checks if both queens are set if not skip using `continue` like that:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < queens.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < queens.length; j++) {
        if (queens[i] == null || queens[j] == null) {
            continue;
        }
        // rest of the method here
    }
}
```

You should also add a `break` once a collision has been detected by giving a label to the main loop and using this label with your `break` as next:

```
main: for (int i = 0; i < queens.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < queens.length; j++) {
        // previous test here
        if (collision detected) {
            isInCollision = true;
            break main;
        }
    }
}
```

This will break the double `for loop` as soon as a collision has been detected.
Another way to do the same this is simply doing `return true;` instead of affecting `true` to `isInCollision` then returning the value after the loops.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you didn't place queens on all places in `queens[]`:

```
if(matrix[i][j] == 1){
     queens[i] = new Queen(i, j);
}
```

Therefore, if one spot in `queens[]` is not set here, it will be `null` and therefore `queens[j].getX(`) or `queens[j].getY()` will produce NPE. So, check if this `array` is filled correctly before doing any operation with it (do it between fors).